# Amateur RPG fun - follow-up

Tags: python, game, adventure-game

I have [posted before](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70436/amateur-rpg-fun), and the code was very bulky and ugly. Here is the new and improved version.

```
#RPG_TEST
#Dennis Gordick
#Brandon McCurry
#10/21/2014

#file system fully works, if you don't understand how to use it ask Brandon
"""
Task list:
allow player to leave game
create different types of monsters
improve shop inventory
gain skill points every level to improve yourself
add multiple save files
monster creator file-(Goal is to make a program that creates new monsters via user input, and is added to Enemies.py
"""
import random
import time
import pickle, shelve
from Enemies import Player, Monster, Shop_Keeper, Monster_Boss




class main():
    def __init__(self):
        response=self.valid_input("New game or Load game?",["load","new"])
        if response == "load":
            try:
                f = shelve.open("save.dat")
                attribute = f["attributes"]
                person = attribute[0]
                f.close()
                print("Success!")
            except:
                print("Save file is corrupt or doesn't exist")
                response="new"
        if response=="new":
            Name=input("What is your name?")
            Race=self.valid_input("What is your race? (Human, Elf, Dwarf) ", ["human","elf","dwarf"])
            #Race=input("What is your race? (Your choices are Human, Elf, and Dwarf.)")
            Class=self.valid_input("What is your class? (Warrior, Archer, Mage) ", ["warrior","archer","mage"])
            #Class=input("What is your class? (Your choices are Warrior, Archer, and Mage.")
            person = Player(Name, Race, Class)

        while person.health > 0:
            person.update()
            explore=self.valid_input("Do you want to explore, go to town, look at some info, or save? ", ["explore","town","save","info"])
            #explore=input("Do you want to explore or go to town or look at some stats/info or even save? (only say explore or town or info or save)")
            turns=1
            if explore=="explore":
                lvl=self.valid_int("What level monsters?")
                print("You explore")
                turns=1
                while turns < 100 and int(person.health) > 0:
                    encounter=random.randint(1,100)

                    #normal fight
                    if int(encounter) >=70:
                        enemy = Monster(lvl,person)
                        print("You encounterd a LVL: "+str(enemy.lvl)+" Monster!")
                        self.fight(person, enemy)
                        person.kills += 1

                    elif int(encounter)<70:
                        loot = random.randint(1,100)
                        trap = random.randint(1,100)

                        if int(loot)>=60:
                            person.gold=int(person.gold)+int(lvl)
                            print("You found "+str(lvl)+" gold")
                            print("You have a total of "+str(person.gold)+" gold")
                            print()
                        elif int(loot)<=10:
                            if int(trap)>=50:
                                person.health=int(person.health)-10
                                print("You step on a trap")
                                print("You lost ten health")
                                print("Your total health is "+str(person.health))
                                print()

                    if int(turns)== 100:
                        #Boss fight
                        boss=random.randint(1,10)
                        if int(boss)>5:
                            print("Boss Fight!")
                            run=self.valid_input("Do you fight or run?", ["fight","run"])
                            if run.lower() == "fight":
                                satan = Monster_Boss(lvl,person)
                                self.fight(person, satan)
                                person.boss_kills += 1


                    turns+=1
                    print("End of turn "+ str(turns)+"\n")
                    time.sleep(1.0)

            elif explore=="info":
                 print("Level",str(person.lvl))
                 print("Total kills",str(person.kills))
                 print("Total boss kills",str(person.boss_kills))
                 print("Total gold",str(person.gold))
                 print("Total potions",str(person.potions))
                 print("Total xp", str(person.xp))

            elif explore=="save":
                f = shelve.open("save.dat")
                attributes = [person]
                f["attributes"] = attributes
                f.sync()
                f.close()
                print("\nSaved!\n")

            #Going to town (giggity)
            while explore=="town":
                town=self.valid_input("Where do you want to go? (shop, inspector, blacksmith, tavern, leave)", ["shop","inspector","blacksmith","tavern","leave"])

                if town=="shop":
                    print("Your gold "+str(person.gold))
                    print("The shopkeep says 'We only have potions of health! They are 20 gold each!'")
                    bought=input("How many do you want?")
                    if bought.isdigit():
                        cost=int(bought)*20
                        if int(person.gold)>=int(cost):
                            person.potions+=int(bought)
                            person.gold-=int(cost)
                            print("Gold left "+str(person.gold))
                            print("Total potions "+str(person.potions))
                        else:
                            print("'Your to poor! Come back with some gold fool!'\nThe shopkeeper kicks you out.")
                    elif bought.strip("-").isdigit():
                        print("Aye. Trying to pull a fast one on me are ya?")
                        keep = Shop_Keeper(person, bought)
                        self.fight(person, keep)
                        if person.health > 0:
                            person.potions += int(bought)*-1
                elif town=="inspector":
                    print("Coming soon")

                elif town=="blacksmith":
                    print("Coming soon")

                elif town=="leave":
                    explore = "leave"

                while town=="tavern":
                    print("Hello traveler, what can I do for you? A drink? Or the latest rumore?")
                    bar_keep=self.valid_input("Whats your choice? (drink, rumore, or leave)", ["drink","rumore","leave"])

                    if bar_keep=="drink":
                        print("Drinks cost one gold.")
                        drink=self.valid_input("Do you want a drink? ",["yes","no"])

                        while drink=="yes" and person.gold > 0:
                            person.gold=int(person.gold)-1
                            print("Your gold: "+str(person.gold))
                            print("You get drunk out of your mind.")
                            drink = input("Another? ")

                    if bar_keep=="rumore":
                        if int(person.lvl) < 20:
                            print("I don't know anything.")
                        else:
                            print("No, rumors at the moment.")

                    if bar_keep=="leave":
                        print("Goodbye")
                        town = ""
    def fight(self, person, enemy):
        while int(enemy.health) > 0 and person.health > 0:
            print("Your Health: "+str(person.health))
            print(enemy.name + " Health: "+str(enemy.health))
            attack=input("Do you attack or use a potion? ")
            #your turn
            if attack == "attack":
                hit=random.randint(1,100)
                if int(hit)<=75:
                    dmg=person.dmg()
                    enemy.health-=int(dmg)
                    print("\nYou did "+ str(dmg)+" damage")
                else:
                    print("You missed!")
            elif attack=="potion":
                if person.potions > 0:
                    person.health=90+int(person.extra_health)
                    print("Potions left... "+str(person.potions))
                else:
                    print("You have no potions... You just waisted your turn!")
            else:
                print("You sit there and take it")
            #enemies turn
            if int(enemy.health) > 0:
                if enemy.potions > 0 and enemy.health < person.dmg_min:
                    enemy.health += enemy.max_health//4
                    enemy.potions -= 1
                    print("The " + str(enemy.name) + " drank a potion")
                else:
                    monster_hit_chance=random.randint(1,100)
                    if int(monster_hit_chance)<=60:
                        person.health=int(person.health)-int(enemy.dmg)
                        print("The " + str(enemy.name) + " did "+ str(enemy.dmg)+" damage")
                        if person.health <= 0:
                            print("You died")
                    else:
                        print("The " + str(enemy.name) + " missed!")

            #loot and xp for normal monster
            else:
                person.xp+=int(enemy.xp)
                print("\nThe " + str(enemy.name) + " died\n")
                print("XP gained: "+ str(enemy.xp))
                print("Your XP: "+ str(person.xp))
                loot_chance=random.randint(1,100)
                if int(loot_chance) <10:
                    print("No loot :(")
                    print("Your gold "+str(person.gold))
                elif int(loot_chance) <90:
                    print("Your gold sir. It this many..." +str(enemy.gold))
                    if enemy.loot != "":
                        print("There was also a " + str(enemy.loot) + " on him.")
                        line = "Would you like to replace it with your " + str(person.weapon) + "? "
                        opt = self.valid_input(line, ["yes","no"])
                        if opt.lower() == "yes":
                            person.weapon = enemy.loot
                            print("Congradulations! Your new weapon is a " + str(person.weapon))
                    person.gold+=int(enemy.gold)
                    print("Your gold "+str(person.gold))
                else:
                    print("Rare loot! 1 potion!")
                    person.potions+=1
                    print("\nYour total potions "+str(person.potions))

    def valid_input(self, question, valid):
        response = input(question)
        while response.lower() not in valid:
            print("Valid responses: ")
            for i in valid:
                print(i)
            response = input(question)
        return response

    def valid_int(self, question):
        response = input(question)
        while not response.isdigit():
            print("That is not a number")
            response = input(question)
        return int(response)


main()
```

There are some new files as well for the enemies.

```
import random
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, race, Class):
        self.name = name
        self.race = race
        self.Class = Class
        self.potions = 0
        self.gold = 0
        self.lvl = 1
        self.xp = 0
        self.extra_health = self.lvl*10
        self.health = 90+self.extra_health
        self.max_health = self.health
        self.dmg_min = self.lvl
        self.dmg_max = self.lvl*6
        self.kills = 0
        self.boss_kills = 0
        if self.Class=="Warrior":
            self.weapon = "Sword"
        elif self.Class=="Archer":
            self.weapon=="Bow"
        else:
            self.weapon="Staff"
        print("A " + self.weapon + " is your weapon.")
        print("The "+str(self.weapon)+" weilding "+ str(self.Class)+" of the "+ str(self.race)+" clan, went out on an adventure. There name was "+str(self.name)) 

    def dmg(self):
        return random.randint(self.dmg_min, self.dmg_max)

    def update(self):
        lvl_xp = 90 + int(self.extra_health)
        while int(self.xp) >= int(lvl_xp):
            self.lvl+=1
            print("Level Up! " + str(self.lvl))
            self.dmg_min = self.lvl
            self.dmg_max = self.lvl*6
            self.extra_health = self.lvl*10
            self.health = 90+self.extra_health
            self.max_health = self.health
            lvl_xp = 90 + int(self.extra_health)

class Monster():
    def __init__(self, lvl, player):
        self.lvl = int(lvl)
        self.dmg = int(lvl)
        self.xp = int(lvl)//int(player.lvl)*2
        self.gold = random.randint(int(lvl)//2,int(lvl)*2)
        self.name = "Monster"
        self.health = lvl*2
        self.max_health = self.health
        self.heal = lvl*10
        self.potions = 0
        lootable = random.randint(1,100)
        if lootable > 90:
            self.loot = random.choice(["Sword","Dagger","Staff"])
        else:
            self.loot = ""
class Shop_Keeper():
    def __init__(self, player, potions):
        potions = int(potions)*-1
        self.lvl = potions*10
        self.dmg = potions*10
        self.xp = self.lvl//int(player.lvl)*2
        self.gold = potions*10+int(player.lvl)*2
        self.name = "Shop Keeper"
        self.health = self.lvl*2
        self.max_health = self.health
        self.loot = "Dagger"
        self.potions = potions

class Monster_Boss():
    def __init__(self, lvl, player):
        self.lvl = lvl
        self.dmg = lvl*3
        self.xp = lvl//player.lvl*6
        self.gold = lvl*100
        self.name = "Boss"
        self.health = player.health
        self.max_health = self.health
        self.loot = random.choice(["Battle Axe", "Club"])
        self.potions = 0
```

And the save file did not really change as well:

```
import shelve

#opens file
f = shelve.open("save.dat")
gold = 2
potions = "3"
#sets all variables as a dictionary
f["attributes"] = {"gold": gold, "potions": potions}
#f.sync() adds all any f["whatever"] to the file
f.sync()
#always close after use!!!
f.close()

#reopen file later to read the contents
f = shelve.open("save.dat")
#save the variables still in dictionary form to a new variable
attributes = f["attributes"]
#always close after use!!!
f.close()
#access each variable individually, and save them to a new variable to match the rest of your code.
gold = attributes["gold"]
print(gold)
```

Comment: @Josay Hey... Could you review the new code? It is based off your recomendations

Comment: Your code doesn't work, what are the random words before `class main` supposed to do?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm sorry... They are in the works... They can be deleted... They where not supposed to be posted here.. :) I'll fix it in the post. They were the only thing added

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basic style/layout stuff:

- Python has a [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - e.g. `Shop_Keeper` should be `ShopKeeper`, `Player.Class` should be `Player.class_`, whitespace (blank lines, etc.) should be reviewed.
- It would be good to see some [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for your classes and methods. I like the [Google style](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html), but others are available.

---

You have an opportunity to do some real OOP and reduce duplication, here; all of your characters have e.g. `lvl`, `xp`, `gold`, so why not abstract out to:

```
class Character(object):

    def __init__(self, lvl, xp, gold, ...):
        self.xp = xp
        self.lvl = lvl
        self.gold = gold
```

Then your shopkeeper is:

```
class ShopKeeper(Character):

    def __init__(self, player, potions):
        potions = int(potions) * -1
        super(ShopKeeper, self).__init__(potions*10, ...)
        ...
```

Also, some of the calculated attributes would be easier as properties:

```
class Player(Character):

    @property
    def extra_health(self): 
        return self.lvl * 10
```

Now the value changes automatically if the `Player`'s `lvl` increases.

---

It is not clear why `main` is a class. It seems to be used mainly as a collection of helper methods (e.g. `valid_input`, `valid_int`) which would be better packaged as simple functions - note that very few of the methods include references to `self` attributes or other methods. Also, using `__init__` to run things is unconventional - if you did have some kind of `main` class, I would expect it to be called like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

i.e. first instantiate the class, then call some method to run it. Note the guard to prevent this running if you `from wherever import Main` later on.

---

Your locations could be classes, too. For example:

```
class Tavern(Location):
    ...

if town == "tavern":
    player.enter(Tavern())
```

This allows you to make the `town` neater:

```
TOWN = {'tavern': Tavern, ...}

player.enter(TOWN[town]())
```

---

Some of the functionality could be moved to the `Character` classes, e.g.

```
class Player(Character):

    CLASSES = ["warrior", "archer", "mage"]
    RACES = ["human", "elf", "dwarf"]

    def __init__(self, name, race, class, ...):
        ...
        super(Player, self).__init__(lvl, xp, gold, ...)
        ...

    def fight(self, enemy):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def from_input(cls):
        name = input("What is your name?")
        race = valid_input("What is your race?", cls.RACES)
        class_ = valid_input("What is your class?", cls.CLASSES)
        return cls(name, race, class_, ...)
```

Note that this is neater if `valid_input` doesn't included the valid options in the prompt - this leads to duplication of the input data (e.g. `valid_input("What is your race? (Human, Elf, Dwarf) ", ["human","elf","dwarf"])` includes the same data twice.)

Comment: Thank you for your feed back :) I will have you notified when i update the game again. I will definitely take what you said into consideration... Give me a few days to update :)

Comment: You should read through what [Josay told you](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/70444/32391) again too - there are some things (e.g. dictionaries) that you have not yet implemented.

Comment: ya... I did not get all the things updated... And i plan on adding more dictionaries... But I'm still learning how to use them properly